# rspec test model for minimum and maximum values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm having some trouble finding the most elegant way to test the range of an attribute in my model. My model looks like:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :hours

  validates :hours, presence: true, 
    :numericality => { :greater_than => 0, :less_than => 24 }
end
```

My rspec tests look like:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Entry do
  let(:entry) { FactoryGirl.create(:entry) }

  subject { entry }

  it { should respond_to(:hours) }
  it { should validate_presence_of(:hours) }
  it { should validate_numericality_of(:hours) }


  it { should_not allow_value(-0.01).for(:hours) }
  it { should_not allow_value(0).for(:hours) }
  it { should_not allow_value(24).for(:hours) }
    # is there a better way to test this range?


end
```

This test works, but is there a better way to test the minimum and maximum values? My way seems clunky. It seems easy to test the length of a value, but I'm not seeing how to test the values of a number. I've tried something like this:

```
it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:hours).in_range(0..24) }
```

But that is expecting an inclusion error, and I can't get my test to pass. Maybe I'm not configuring it correctly?

---

I ended up testing at, above, and below both of my boundaries as suggested below. Because I don't restrict to integers I testing to two decimal places. I think that's probably "good enough" for the purposes of my app.

```
it { should_not allow_value(-0.01).for(:hours) }
it { should_not allow_value(0).for(:hours) }
it { should allow_value(0.01).for(:hours) }
it { should allow_value(23.99).for(:hours) }
it { should_not allow_value(24).for(:hours) }
it { should_not allow_value(24.01).for(:hours) }
```

Comment: Isn't your range off in your test?  Shouldn't it be: it { should ensure_inclusion_of(:hours).in_range(1..23) }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if all valid values are covered you can write something like:

```
it "should allow valid values" do
  (1..24).to_a.each do |v|
    should allow_value(v).for(:hours)
end
```

You can also implement boundary testing. For each boundary one can test at, above and below any boundary to ensure that the conditional logic works as expected [as posted by David Chelimsky-2](http://ruby.11.n6.nabble.com/Checking-for-Range-td3487220.html).

So you would have 6 tests in total for the 2 boundaries.

Comment: This seems impractical for large ranges. And what if you wanted to test a range of Floats?

Comment: This won't work for floats: "Iterates over the elements rng, passing each in turn to the block. You can only iterate if the start object of the range supports the succ method (which means that you can’t iterate over ranges of Float objects)." http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html

Comment: Ok, thanks for that link to the David Chelimsky post. Testing boundaries makes sense, even if it's a little bit "clunky". I was hoping for something like this, except for values instead of length: it { should ensure_length_of(:password).is_at_least(6).is_at_most(20) }  It seems like a min/max validation matcher would be pretty easy to set up, but I'll do it the "manual" way for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The should matcher you are looking for is the is_greater_than and is_less_than matcher. They can be chained onto the validate_numericality_of matcher as follows

```
it {should validate_numericality_of(:hours).is_greater_than(0).is_less_than(24)}
```

This will validate that the numbers in your range are resulting in a valid variable and that the error being returned for numbers out of that range is correct. You are correct that the ensures_inclusion_of matcher does not work because it is expecting a different type of error, but this validation should work fine.